# how do i get the data from a database and store it into a text file?

Tags: java, derby

I am new to databases in Java and i am trying to export the data from 1 table and store it in a text file. At the moment the code below writes to the text file however all on one line? can anyone help?

**My Code**

```
    private static String listHeader() {
            String output = "Id Priority From                           Label  Subject\n";
            output += "== ======== ====                           =====  =======\n";
            return output;
        }
    public static String Export_Message_Emails() {
            String output = listHeader();
            output +="\n";
            try {
                ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * from messages ORDER BY ID ASC");
                while (res.next()) { // there is a result
                    output += formatListEntry(res);
                    output +="\n";

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                return null;
            }
            return output;
        }
public void exportCode(String File1){
     try {
                if ("Messages".equals(nameOfFile)){
                 fw = new FileWriter(f);   
                //what needs to be written here
                //fw.write(MessageData.listAll());
                fw.write(MessageData.Export_Message_Emails());
                    fw.close(); 

          }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a hard coded value of "\n". Instead use `System.getProperty("line.separator");` or if you are using Java 7 or greater, you can use `System.lineSeparator();`

Comment: Where do I write System.llineSeparator() ;

Comment: instead of output +="\n"  write output += System.lineSeparator()

Answer (score 0):

Try `String.format("%n")` instead `"\n"`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna assume you are using Windows and that you are opening your file with notepad. If that is correct then it is not really a problem with your output but with the editor you are viewing it with.

1. Try a nicer editor, ie. Notepad++
2. Do as the other answers suggest and use System.getProperty("line.separator"); or similar.
3. Use a Writer implementation such as, PrintWriter.

Personally I prefer "\n" over the system line separator, which on Windows is "\r\n".

EDIT: Added option 3

Comment: If there are chances for the line feed to be "\r\n", why would you hard code "\n" where it could be wrong versus pulling the line feed from the system itself?

Comment: Well, just because the system for arcane reasons use a specific line separator doesn't mean that you **have to** use it. I often try and only use "\n" even when I'm on Windows (I setup Eclipse, Git and such to use Unix style).

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're trying to practice your Java programming (which is perfectly fine of course!), you can export all the data from one table and store it in a file by using the SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_EXPORT_TABLE system procedure: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.11/ref/rrefexportproc.html